# Sum in Magic star puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, puzzle, magic-square

I have the following problem:

*Place the first 11 natural numbers in the circles so that the sum of the four numbers at the tops of each of the five sectors-beams of the star equals 25*.

[image]

I came up with the fact that $6$ should be central number as the sum of numbers from 1 to 11 is 66. But how should I distribute all threes of sum=19 - i don't know. Would appreciate **any** help.

Source of the contest [link](http://mmmf.msu.ru/archive/20122013/z5/z5300313.html)

Comment: great community, down-voting the post without any criticism made. Just downvote though a lot effort taken. Nice

Comment: What effort?  To post the image of a picture and ask users to solve this for you?  We don't get paid here; no one gets paid.  So you can pout about us not doing your work for you.  We try to assist users who demonstrate effort, just because.  By the way, if this is a contest question then please include the source and importantly, date of the contest.

Comment: I don't want anybody to solve this for me. I just want **any** ideas! And I think that just downvoting makes the no point of this forum. I did provided my idea and want to eleborate on it or cut it off entirely, @amWhy
The contest was in 2013

Comment: Thanks for the added information.  Can you add that via an edit to your post?  I see some clarification you added.  Please understand that we get tons of "problem statement questions", and as a site, we have taken great pains to establish quality standards.  I admit that for earnest enthusiasts, it may come across as very off-putting;  please be patient with us; and we'll, (at least I) will try to be more patient too,

Comment: Already did, @amWhy

Comment: Indeed.  I appreciate it.  Most people here really want to help others; there are some useful links, about "good questions"; if you are interested, I'll add them.

Comment: You're new here, so let me explain why I down-voted:  First, the fluff about "crushing your brain" is just that... fluff.  Who *cares* that the problem came from your friend and such?  It wastes readers' times and does not contribute the clarification of the problem or especially *what you've tried*.  It is essential you explain what you've done in greater detail.  Questions like "I can't solve this... give me hints," without more details, are not well regarded here.  Further, might this problem belong better on a puzzle site?  Read about how to post questions... you'll get better replies.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your arguments on downvoting, @DavidG.Stork

Comment: Revision is much better.  Thanks.  ($+1$)

Comment: [puzzling.se], a potential site for puzzle related question, mentioned by @DavidG.Stork

Comment: "I came up with the  fact that 6 should be central number as the sum of numbers from 1 to 11 is 66."   Myself, I came up with the fact that 7 should be the central number as  "seven" rhymes with "eleven", which seems about as relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Let the central number be $C$, sum of five numbers in inner (inverted) pentagon be $P$ and sum of five numbers in outer pentagon be $Q$. Each sector has sum $25$, we can sum all five sectors to get a sum of $5 \times 25 =125$. In this total sum, numbers in outer pentagon are present only once, numbers in inner pentagon twice and the central number five times.
$$5C+2P+Q=125$$
Subtracting $C+P+Q=66$ from this gives $4C+P=59$.

Choosing $C=11$ gives $P=15, Q=40$. Since $15=1+2+3+4+5$ and $40=6+7+8+9+10$, very first choice looks promising.

It makes sense to fill outer pentagon first since numbers appear only once.

One sector can be

```
   6 
 /   \ 

 \   / 
   11
```

Remaining two numbers on this sector must be $5,3$. Continuing on and playing around a bit, I got

```
              6
         3        5     
  10         11         7
        1          2
             4
    9                8
```

which satisfies given conditions.